# postgresql get list of disabled foreign keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, information-schema

How to get a list of all disabled foreign keys for all tables in PostgreSQL?

I have example: in MSSQL, it is done like this:

```
select * from sys.foreign_keys where is_disabled=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the system trigger that belongs to the foreign key constraint is disabled:

```
SELECT t.tgrelid::regclass AS table_name,
       c.conname AS constraint
FROM pg_trigger AS t
   JOIN pg_constraint AS c
      ON t.tgconstraint = c.oid
WHERE t.tgenabled = 'D';
```